# length of string does not match what is printed by var_dump() in php

Tags: php

This is inside of a wordpress application, specifically `set_url_scheme`.

code:

```
var_dump($url);
```

output:

```
string(21) "https://localhost:8888"
```

that string has 22 characters. this string is the result of `preg_replace`, it works up until a certain point and then discontinues working and returns these strange strings.

This only seems to be happening with "http://" -> "https://" specifically. there aren't issues with "htttp://" for example.

Comment: Post the `preg_replace` line and var_dumps of its parameters.

Comment: It seems like error is somewhere else http://ideone.com/HebMSw